# What is the pros and cons in using FormsAuthentication to persist login cookie?

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies, authentication, .net-4.0

What is the pros and cons in using FormsAuthentication to persist a login cookie?

I see that StackOverflow ignore `FormsAuthentication` and instead implemented a different strategy to persist a login cookie.

### Pros

1. Out of the box implementation for persistent login feature.

### Cons

1. The login feature depends on the `machine key` which mean that I need to make sure that the machine key is the same on all the servers in the farm.
2. The cookie contains wired encrypted values that don't really make sense to store in the cookie.

Answer (score 2):

Other OOTB features of Formsauthentication are:

- *encryption* and *decryption* of the cookie
- sliding expiration
- easy integration with other asp.net features such as membership provider (if you want to use it)

On the other hand, I don't really see the problem with the *machine key*: it can be set explicitly in the web.config, so there should not be a problem to use the same key when deploying in a server farm.

Microsoft has an excellent [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx#pagexplained0002_aspnetforms) describing what the cookie contains (see excerpt below). I don't really find any values that make no sense to be there:

> - **Expires**. This property specifies the expiration date and time
>     for the cookie. Forms authentication
>     only sets this value if your code
>     indicates that a persistent
>     forms-authentication cookie should be
>     issued.
> - **Domain**. This property specifies the domain with which the cookie is
>     associated. The default value is null.
>           o HasKeys. This property indicates whether the cookie has
>     subkeys.
> - **HttpOnly**. This property specifies whether the cookie can be
>     accessed by client script. In ASP.NET
>     2.0, this value is always set to true. Internet Explorer 6 Service Pack 1
>     supports this cookie attribute, which
>     prevents client-side script from
>     accessing the cookie from the
>     document.cookie property. If an
>     attempt is made to access the cookie
>     from client-side script, an empty
>     string is returned. The cookie is
>     still sent to the server whenever the
>     user browses to a Web site in the
>     current domain.
>
>   - Note   Web browsers that do not support the HttpOnly cookie attribute
>       either ignore the cookie or ignore the
>       attribute, which means that the
>       session is still subject to cross-site
>       scripting attacks.
> - **Path**. This property specifies the virtual path for the cookie. The
>     default value is "/", indicating root
>     directory.
> - **Secure**. This property specifies whether the cookie should only be
>     transmitted over an HTTPS connection.
>     The Secure property should be set to
>     true so that the cookie is protected
>     by SSL encryption.
> - **Version**. This property specifies the version number of the cookie.